# How to create matrix that include range of numbers?

Tags: python

I want to create matrixes that contain range of integers like

```
[[range(1, 3), 0, 0],
 [range(5, 7), range(0, 2), 0],
 [0, range(1, 3), 0]]
```

Answer that I expected is

```
[[[1 0 0], [5 0 0], [0, 1, 0]]
 [[2 0 0], [5 0 0], [0, 1, 0]]
 [[1 0 0], [6 0 0], [0, 1, 0]]
 [[2 0 0], [6 0 0], [0, 1, 0]]
 [[1 0 0], [5 0 0], [0, 2, 0]]
 [[2 0 0], [5 0 0], [0, 2, 0]]
 [[1 0 0], [6 0 0], [0, 2, 0]]
 [[2 0 0], [6 0 0], [0, 2, 0]]]
```

rather than range object inside matrix.

I can achieve my goal with using loops

```
def foo(p1_range, p2_range, p3_range)
    for p1 in range(p1_range):
        for p2 in range(p2_range):
            for p3 in range(p3_range):
                yield [[p1 0 0], [p2 0 0], [0, p3, 0]]
```

Is there any pythonic way to solve this?

Note: I normaly need 7 parameters in my main code... It looks awful with this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to reduce indentation levels and eliminate the nested loops:

```
from itertools import product

def foo(p1_range, p2_range, p3_range):
    for p1, p2, p3 in product(p1_range, p2_range, p3_range):
        yield [[p1, 0, 0], [p2, 0, 0], [0, p3, 0]]
```